# awk read error bad address

Tags: text-processing, awk, large-files

I have a file that is roughly 30GB. I am using,

```
awk ' $1 <= 2000 ' myfile.txt >> myfile_new.txt
```

But, I get this error after a while -

```
awk: read error (Bad address)
```

I guess this is because the file is too large. Is there any way to get past this? How else can I do this? 
What I need to do is quite simple, I have to extract all records that have value less than 2000 in a column.

Comment: Have you tried `mawk`?

Comment: @coffeMug `mawk` is probably the cause of this, errors like this are fairly commonplace when operating on very large files with it. `gawk` will likely not have this issue.

Comment: @ChrisDown Is it possible to feed the file in smaller parts to `awk` in order to avoid this?

Comment: `split –bytes=100m /path/to/large/file /path/to/output/file/prefix`. Pick a diff. size, 1G?

Comment: A simple python script might help you achieve the goal. You can probably edit the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669428/process-very-large-20gb-text-file-line-by-line) link.

Comment: @slm What if the split separated characters from a line's first column into two separate files? Worse yet, what if the file is in UTF-8?

Comment: @JosephR. - agreed that was just a example. Without knowing the data it's difficult to comment beyond just an example 8-)

Comment: @ChrisDown You were right, gawk worked fine. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using `mawk`, which has some optimisations that can result in errors like this when dealing with particularly large data. `gawk` will likely not have these issues when running it in the same way.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted.  This was exactly the case for me. The file was too large, and I got the same error referenced in the question, and upon running `man awk`, realized that `awk` was referencing `mawk`.  I installed `gawk`, ran the same commmand, no error.

Comment: Just saw @hashping actually told you this was the issue and requested this to be re-stated as the answer. There is no reason this answer should have received any downvotes without comment or explanation.  Thanks again for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Perl can do it,

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while(my $ln=<>){ my($f) = split(/\s/,$ln); if($f<=2000) { print $ln;} }
```

So can Python and Ruby,

```
#!/bin/env ruby
while( rec = gets() ) do
  fld = rec.match(/^(\w+)\s/)
  if(fld[1].to_i <= 2000) then puts rec end
end
```

Comment: Or even more magically: `perl -lane 'print if $F[0]<= 2000' input_file_name >> output_file_name` which is essentially what the OP's `awk` does.

Comment: I love perl golf!